# pass parameters to server from JQuery Template

Tags: jquery

I am getting values in jquery template through wcf service in json format.

```
<script id="ExItemTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
     <span class="some class" > ${user_id} </span>
</script>
```

Here, `${user_id}` is replaced with the id which is the value getting from wcf service.

Method is present on server side which takes string as parameter and returns user name on server side code.. I want to call this method from this template where user id is present.

NOTE: template executes multiple times. so each time getting new id there.
using Asp.net and Csharp.net